# Add AWS IAM users to AWS Cognito Pool

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-cognito

I'm a newbie to AWS, I'm building an application where the users should be logged in via AWS account.

So I created a user pool and authenticated via AWS SDK using the federated identities. But the users were created manually in the Cognito UI.But the requirement is to authenticate the user if they already resides in AWS as an IAM user. But AWS cognito does not provide a workflow to import the IAM users to cognito pool. So is there another way to accomplish this via AWS ? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is currently not possible. Although AWS Cognito Federated Identities allows, federating an external identity provider to grant AWS access, the other way around is not possible.

In addition, there is no method in AWS IAM SDK to verify AWS Username and Password, which also limits verifying them through your own implementation.