# AWS - type of users and how they can assume an IAM role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam

## Question

Clarify how a **user** in AWS can assume an IAM role. It is confusing to me because it appears **user/identity** in AWS can be different depending on a context such as, IAM User, Cognito User Pool user, Cognito Federated User.

### Background

Trying to understand the relations among **users** and **identities** in AWS and how each **user** can assume an IAM role.

Also in AWS, **user/unauthenticated** and **identity (authenticated user)** seem to be different concepts and both can assume an IAM role, hence it looks **authenticated** is not a pre-requisite to assume an IAM role, which is also confusing to me.

1. IAM **User/Identity** (identity = user authenticated e.g. via AWS CLI with AWS ID/Secret)
2. Cognito User Pool **User/Identity** (authenticated)
3. Cognito Federated Identity Pool **User/Identity** (authenticated)
4. Are there any other user types?

---

**IAM User (authenticated)**

I believe this is an identity of a **user** identified by logging into the AWS console, or via CLI/SDK with an AWS access key ID/secret. This **user** can assume an IAM role by [Switching to a Role (AWS Management Console)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-console.html) or programatically [assume-role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sts/assume-role.html) with CLI/SDK. Is this correct?

---

**Cognito User Pool User**

I believe this **user** exists within Cognito only in an AWS account and **has nothing to do with an IAM User**. Currently there is no way to map an **IAM user** to a **Cognito user** (neither user pool nor federated identity pool) as in [Add AWS IAM users to AWS Cognito Pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49550733/add-aws-iam-users-to-aws-cognito-pool).

It looks there are few ways to assign an IAM role to a Cognito User Pool **user** or **identity (authenticated user)**.

One way is to assign an IAM role to a Cognito User Pool Group in which users are added to. An authenticated user in the User Pool Group can assume the IAM role automatically.

[image]

Another way is to use a Cognito Federated Identity Pool by federating with a Cognito User Pool and assign an IAM role to the federated identity pool. In this case, an Cognito User Pool user/identity (authenticated) is equivalent with an Cognito Federated Identity Pool user/identity (authenticated).

I suppose a user will be authenticated with a Cognito User Pool workflow via the Cognito Federated Identity Pool. Then the user can assume both the IAM role mapped to the Cognito User Pool Group **AND** the IAM role mapped to the Cognito Federated Identity (authenticated).

Are these correct, or will the user only be able to assume only one of the IAM roles? What if there are multiple accounts in an [AWS organisation](https://aws.amazon.com/organizations/). Should each account create its Cognito User Pool to manage the same set of users, or have one Cognito User Pool in an account and share the Cognito User Pool among accounts via a Cognito Fedatated Identities pointing to the User Pool?

[image]

---

**Cognito Federated Identity Pool User**

If the federation is not with Cognito, such as with Facebook, then an Cognito Federated Identity Pool **user/identity** has nothing to do with the Cognito User Pool user/identity and the **user** is that of Facebook. The user can assume an IAM role mapped to the Cognito Federated Identity Pool, even when it is unauthenticated. Is this correct?

[image]

---

### Help

I have been looking into AWS Re:Invent videos, AWS documentations but it is a struggle to clearly understand Cognito terms and meanings. If there is a clear, simple, intuitive explanations, kindly provide the references.

Comment: It took my team 20 meetings to develop our AWS user management strategy. At the end, we have no "users" and only roles. But during setup, we have "users" (e.g. IAM users) in order to setup the account. We do it using CloudFormation templates.

Comment: I don't know much about Cognito, but what you said about Users and Roles is accurate.